# mongorestore failed to restore indexes for large data set

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I took a dump of records from my server having a collection of 65.8M records and overall DB records are  74M. It makes around 4.26GB of gzip for this DB.

When I downloaded this gzip.archive dump file on one of my local machine having windows and mongorestore it. It worked successfully and restored all data but while restoring index it gave me the following exception

```
Failed: leads.business: error creating indexes for leads.business: createIndex error: connection(localhost:27017[-5]) unable to decode message length: read tcp 127.0.0.1:51636->127.0.0.1:27017: i/o timeout
2020-05-21T00:15:23.128+0500    74181602 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

So I searched for this exception and found this issue had been fixed in MongoDB JIRA ticket is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2394.

Then I tried restoring the same dump on to my ubuntu machine which has the latest MongoDB version. It didn't give me any exception but seemed to be hanged. I waited for more than half an hour even longer than complete DB restore time. But mongorestore never responded cursor kept on blinking as if something is being processed but nothing happened. I tried this twice on ubuntu.

> *Important Information:*

MongoDB Server Details:

```
OS: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
MongoDB Version: 4.2.6
```

MongoDB Local Machine Details:

```
OS: Windows 10
MongoDB Version: 4.2.0
```

MongoDB Local Machine Details:

```
OS: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       Focal Fossa
MongoDB Version: 4.2.6
```

After updating the Windows machine with MongoDB 4.2.6 to avoid the exception I was getting earlier as per ticket [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2394](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2394.)

Logs:

```
2020-05-21T04:04:16.107+0500    leads.business  27.6GB
2020-05-21T04:04:18.835+0500    leads.business  27.7GB
2020-05-21T04:04:18.849+0500    restoring indexes for collection leads.business from metadata
```

As can be seen, it started restoring indexes on 2020-05-21T04:04:18.849+0500 and now it's 4:54 almost an hour has been passed

It can be verified from screenshot as well
[image]

If anyone else faced this issue please share your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine on MongoDB 4.2.6, it's just taking a lot of time, please find below logs.

```
2020-05-21T03:25:19.233+0500    preparing collections to restore from
....
....
....
2020-05-21T04:04:18.835+0500    leads.business  27.7GB
2020-05-21T04:04:18.849+0500    restoring indexes for collection leads.business from metadata
2020-05-21T05:14:01.598+0500    finished restoring leads.business (65803772 documents, 0 failures)
2020-05-21T05:14:01.658+0500    74181602 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

> - As it can be seen collection restore process(except indexes) starts at
>     03:25:19 and ends at 04:04:18.
> - Index restore started at 04:04:18 and ended at 05:14:01

Conclusion restoring indexes is taking more time than restoring the whole collection. But its working fine.